# PHP MYSQL query, finding connections

Tags: php, mysql

For experimentation I'm building a script which is designed to find flight connections using PHP & mysql.

I have a database called "schedules" similar to the following:

```
dep_airport, arr_airport, flt_num

LHR JFK 100,
LHR FRA 200,
JFK MIA 300
```

Lets assume someone wants to fly from LHR to MIA. They would need to connect in JFK, so take flights 100 LHR - JFK, and then change to flight 300 JFK - MIA.

If I run a query:

```
SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE dep_airport = 'LHR' AND arr_airport = 'MIA'
```

The query will return null, as there is no direct connection. How can I query the database for it to find the relationship that LHR - MIA does exist but via JFK?

Comment: You're going to need additional information as there is not enough here to make a.....wait for it.....connection.

Comment: Is that you Barney?

Comment: @JayBlanchard as in "connecting flights"? ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard could you point me in the right direction? What kind of additional information? Thanks

Comment: You have to know how the flight number changed or how the connection is made from one flight to another. Having just the airport identifier is not enough. What makes up the connection?

Comment: @JayBlanchard What I was thinking was something along those lines.

Find all flights departing LHR and all flight arriving at MIA, then somehow filter them so that the arrival airport for LHR-JFK and departure airport JFK-MIA is found if that makes sense?

Comment: OK - so what would you use to connect the two flights? Time? Carrier? Manifest? Just because a flight goes from JFK - MIA doesn't mean it originated at LHR or originated at LHR in time to make the connection at JFK.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Im not trying to necessarily connect the flights. I want a query which will find all possible connections between LHR and MIA, in this case theres no direct connection if that clarifies it more.

Answer (score 0):

To really make it work, you'll need more info - arrival and departure times for instance.

If you limit your choices to one-stops (max two flights), then a simple SQL join will find your flights.

```
SELECT *
FROM `schedules` a
JOIN `schedules` b
ON a.`arr_airport` = b.`dep_airport`
WHERE a.`dep_airport` = 'LHR' AND b.`arr_airport` = 'MIA'
```

Of course, you would check for direct flights before running this query. Also, you would need to put constraints on the arrival and departure times.  Real scheduling software even takes the time to get from one gate to another into consideration, so it isn't just as simple as arrival time < departure time.

If you also need to consider more stops, you would add more joins for queries that would be run after this one.

It is also possible to write a query that would look for non-stops and one stops all at once, but you might want to avoid that for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a try. Im still learning. I simplified the database for now, will try more complex things once I get this working :).

Answer (score 0):

Given your current schema and the way that you clarified your question in comments you could get the information by using a LEFT JOIN on the table in question:

```
SELECT s1.* 
FROM schedules s1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schedules s2
ON s1.arr = s2.dep
WHERE s1.dep = 'LHR'
AND s2.arr = 'MIA'
```

As shown in [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8ba38/3) it returns:

```
dep arr flight
LHR JFK 100
```

Added [another example with an additional flight](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8586b3/1) to show how this would work at most basic level. Again, there are many unaccounted for variables that were asked about in comments but if all you're after is what was asked with the three original columns then this could be the way you would want to go.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.